# Spring Boot @RequestParam default value if boolean expression is true

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to make a request deliver a default value if a boolean expression evaluates to true and the given parameter else. What would be the "Spring" way to do this without writing the if-block in every method?

```java
@RequestMapping("/")
  public String get(@RequestParam String parameter) {
    if (expression)
      return default;
    return parameter;
}
```

Comment: @Paul removed must have read question incorrectly

Comment: @AlexB Thanks! I removed mine as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

If `expression` is always the same then you can move the evaluation to its own method and have your handlers call that:

```java
@RequestMapping("/")
public String get(@RequestParam String parameter) {
  return evaluateParameter(parameter);
}

private String evaluateParameter(String parameter) {
  return expression ? default : parameter;
}
```

If `expression` is not always the same then you have to write the if-block in every method or use the ternary operator as I did above.